# Sorting List of Table objects by their Relations

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, linq

I have a list of table object that has relations between them. and I need to create them in the database. but the problem that sometimes there is a table that reference another table that still not created. and I need to create the reference on the time when I create the table.

Here is a sample :

```
    class Table
    {
        public string TableName{get;set;}

        public List<string> ChildTables{get;set;}
    }


    public void PrepareData()
    {
        var tables = new List<Table>
        {
            new Table {TableName = "TableA",  ChildTables =new List<string>()},
            new Table {TableName = "TableB",   ChildTables =new List<string>()},
            new Table {TableName = "TableC",   ChildTables =new List<string>{"TableG"}},
            new Table {TableName = "TableD",   ChildTables =new List<string>{"TableB"}},
            new Table {TableName = "TableE",   ChildTables =new List<string>{"TableF","TableI"}},
            new Table {TableName = "TableF",   ChildTables =new List<string>{""}},
            new Table {TableName = "TableG",   ChildTables =new List<string>{"TableB","TableA"}},
            new Table {TableName = "TableH",   ChildTables =new List<string>{""}},
            new Table {TableName = "TableI",   ChildTables =new List<string>{""}},
        };



        // Re Order tables based on their relations  

        // first tables that has no relations 

        // second tables that has relations and their tables already ordered in the list.

        // the goal is that we want to create the tables in the database in their relation keys and all of the tables should exist 

        // also if there is a Reference circuit we should invoke an error message and specify where is it 


    }
```

I couldn't figure out how to do it please help

Comment: This is not really about sorting, it's building a reference tree. But the "tables are not created yet" do not fit your sample. You have a sample with 9 given tables and a reference structure between them. Since you store the Name of the table, and not the table itself as reference, it's not a problem if you first store the reference, and later on create the table.

Comment: What about cyclical references? For  example TableA references TableB, and TableB references TableA.

Comment: If you don't need to handle cyclical references, like @TheodorZoulias comments, you can use a topological sort to order them in the required order. If you need to support cyclical references, you need to break them apart, like first create the tables without the foreign key references, then after all the tables are in place, add the references. This could probably be the easiest way anyway, come to think of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this function can help you to sort. But you should confirm that there is no inter-reference that will cause infinite loop. e.g table A refers B, and B refers A.

```
List<Table> SortTableList(List<Table> TableList)
{
    List<Table> resultTable = new List<Table>();
    int tableCount = TableList.Count;
    int confirmedTableCount = 0;
    while(confirmedTableCount < tableCount)
    {
        foreach(var table in TableList)
        {
            if(resultTable.Contains(table) == true) continue;

            bool CanThisTableAddToResult = true;
            foreach(var child in table.ChildTables)
            {
                if(resultTable.Find(tbl => tbl.TableName == child) == null) // this table's child table doesn't exist at result table yet, so it can not be added now.
                {
                    CanThisTableAddToResult = false; 
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(CanThisTableAddToResult == true)
            {
                resultTable.Add(table);
                confirmedTableCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return resultTable;
}
```

Comment: It always sends a cold shiver down my spine when I see someone use something like `if(boolValue == true)` instead of `if(boolValue)`

Comment: every one has his own code style, and it is not essential in current problem.